# VB.net (VS 2013) combobox item.add failing when tiggered from external event?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have no problem adding an item to my combobox using the following code on a button or elsewhere in my project.

```
    CBSpnd.Items.Add("B")
```

however, it seems if I put that same line in a sub that is triggered by an event external to my application ( in my case i'm capturing a selectionchange event from an open excel document), when this line runs the code simply stops. No errors, no exceptions, nothing, and the rest of the routine does not run.

Has anyone run into this before or knows why this is happening? I'll put the relevant code below

```
    Private Event_cellchange As Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler
    Sub AddHandlers()
        Event_cellchange = New Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler( _
            AddressOf CellsChange)
        WS = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Prod Data")
        MWS = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Machine Layout")
        RemoveHandler WS.selectionChange, Event_cellchange
        AddHandler WS.selectionChange, Event_cellchange

    End Sub

    Public Sub CellsChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

        ChangeText(LblOrder, WS.Range("E" & Target.Row).Value)
        ChangeText(LblOtype, WS.Range("B" & Target.Row).Value)
        ChangeText(LblLbs, WS.Range("G" & Target.Row).Value)
        ChangeText(LblClr, WS.Range("AU" & Target.Row).Value)
        'CBSpnd.Items.Add(WS.Range("AI" & Target.Row).Value)
        'CBSpnd.Items.Add(WS.Range("AM" & Target.Row).Value)
        'CBSpnd.Items.Add(WS.Range("AQ" & Target.Row).Value)
        CBAdd("B")    '**** CODE STOPS HERE, NO ERRORS/EXCEPTIONS ****

        UDOP.Text = WS.Range("C" & Target.Row).Value
    End Sub

    Delegate Sub ChangeTextDelegate(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal str As String)
    Private Sub ChangeText(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal str As String)
        If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
            ctrl.Invoke(New ChangeTextDelegate(AddressOf ChangeText), New Object() {ctrl, str})
            Return
        End If
        ctrl.Text = str
    End Sub
```

Comment: Tell Visual Studio to break on all exceptions from Debug > Exceptions menu, and select the check under "Thrown" for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  Hopefully this will cause VS to actually show you the error.  Make sure you turn this option back off when you are done with this error or it will drive you crazy.  I have a feeling your problem may be thread related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is running on a separate thread.  You correctly call methods for the textbox via invoking them on the form's thread; you need to do the same thing when you add the item to the combo box.

Add this to the beginning of your event handler

```
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Excel.Range)(AddressOf CellsChange), {Target})
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This will marshal everything you do in the event handler to the correct thread.  Once you add this you can remove the special code for the text boxes also.

Comment: Beautiful!  This is my first time having to deal with threading and you just made it a whole lot easier.  Thank you.